# JavaScript Issue with JSON objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing, jsp

I've got a function that queries my database and gets a list of usernames-- I've pasted it below:
****dbQuery.jsp****

```
<%! 
org.json.JSONArray dbQuery(String SQL_STRING)
{
// This step will read hibernate.cfg.xml and prepare hibernate for use
org.hibernate.SessionFactory sessionFactory = new     org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
org.hibernate.Session session1 = sessionFactory.openSession();
org.hibernate.Query query = session1.createQuery(SQL_STRING);
java.util.List list = query.list();
org.json.JSONArray jsonArray = new org.json.JSONArray(list);

// Actual contact insertion will happen at this step
session1.flush();
session1.close(); 
return jsonArray;
}
%>
```

I then try to parse through the list of users, but can't get it to work right. Here's what I'm doing:

```
var users = <%=dbQuery("FROM Users")%>; 
alert("User= " + users[0].getAttribute('username'));
```

Why doesn't this work? What is the right syntax to parse through the objects/attributes in this JSON Array?

Comment: what is the error you are getting ? post the errors or issues. It helps the people to solve your problem!

Comment: try users[0].username. Easiest thing to do is console.log(users) to inspect the data structure client-side. Use firefox or chrome.

Comment: The Error Console says, "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'user[0].getAttribute('username')')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
users[0].getAttribute('username')
```

will not work

try

```
users[0].username
```

Comment: Thanks guys! The console.log(X) was a huge help. . .

Comment: sure. I think you were mixing dom with json. json is quite barebones which makes it easier.